# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/inquirer'

Tags: javascript

when I run this command in my project:

```
yarn eject
```

shows this eror:

```
[root@VM-0-16-centos cruise-web]# yarn eject
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-scripts eject
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/inquirer'
Require stack:
- /home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js:23:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/dolphin/sync/source/cruise-web/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js'
  ]
}
```

then I add a dependency in my `package.json`:

```
"react-dev-utils":"11.0.1"
```

then run the command to install and rerun eject:

```
yarn 
yarn eject
```

but the problem still not fixed, what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had the same problem. Check out `react-scripts` version on `package.json`.
I guessed that this (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10083) would be a reason why `yarn eject` throw err.

I was able to solve the problem by installing the last version of react-script:

`npm install react-scripts@4.0.1`